# How to take a screenshot of a scrollable in Selenium using Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium.

I have very long scroll-able form which will automation script will fill, is there a way where I can take screenshot when the page is scrolled down every time (web-driver scrolls to fill the form, I haven't scripted to scroll down as web-driver takes care of it), so that the entire form can be captured in multiple screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. On every swipe You can take screenshot, like as step screenshot.

Here is part of code for screenshot take:

```
public static String takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
    File dest = new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png");

    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, dest);
   return dest.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

And here is the code for vertical swipe:

```
 public static void swipeVertical(WebDriver driver) {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        System.out.println(size);

        int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
        int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
        int startx = size.width / 2;

        new TouchAction(driver)
                .press(startx, starty)
                .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .moveTo(startx, endy)
                .release()
                .perform();
    }
```

so my pseudo code would look like this:

1. WebDriver driver = initDriver();
2. load page and elements
3. inputText(text);
4. takScreenShot(driver);
5. swipe(driver);

...

repeat until end...

Answer (score 0):

You can capture as many screenshots as you want. After fill in each column, after fill in each third column, whatever.

Or you can let the webdriver fill in the whole form and scroll up/down using press pgup/pgdn simulation:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
rob.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```